# Unknown Property Error

Tags: visualforce, callout

I have written a webservice to be called from salesforce.  I generated a class from wsdl:

```
//Generated by wsdl2apex

public class SFtoACSApex {    

    public class ArrayOfAccountInfo {
        public SFtoACSApex.AccountInfo[] AccountInfo;
        private String[] AccountInfo_type_info = new String[]{'AccountInfo','http://tempuri.org/',null,'0','-1','true'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://tempuri.org/','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'AccountInfo'};
    }
    public class AccountInfo {
        public String AccountNumber;
        public String AccountName;
        private String[] AccountNumber_type_info = new String[]{'AccountNumber','http://tempuri.org/',null,'0','1','false'};
        private String[] AccountName_type_info = new String[]{'AccountName','http://tempuri.org/',null,'0','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://tempuri.org/','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'AccountNumber','AccountName'};
    }
    public class AccountSelect_element {
        public String sAccount;
        private String[] sAccount_type_info = new String[]{'sAccount','http://tempuri.org/',null,'0','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://tempuri.org/','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'sAccount'};
    }
    public class AccountSelectResponse_element {
        public SFtoACSApex.ArrayOfAccountInfo AccountSelectResult;
        private String[] AccountSelectResult_type_info = new String[]{'AccountSelectResult','http://tempuri.org/',null,'0','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://tempuri.org/','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'AccountSelectResult'};
    }
    public class SFtoACSSoap {
        public String endpoint_x = 'http://mywebsite.com/WebServices/myservice.asmx';
        public Map<String,String> inputHttpHeaders_x;
        public Map<String,String> outputHttpHeaders_x;
        public String clientCertName_x;
        public String clientCert_x;
        public String clientCertPasswd_x;
        public Integer timeout_x;
        private String[] ns_map_type_info = new String[]{'http://tempuri.org/', 'SFtoACSApex'};
        public SFtoACSApex.ArrayOfAccountInfo AccountSelect(String sAccount) {
            SFtoACSApex.AccountSelect_element request_x = new SFtoACSApex.AccountSelect_element();
            request_x.sAccount = sAccount;
            SFtoACSApex.AccountSelectResponse_element response_x;
            Map<String, SFtoACSApex.AccountSelectResponse_element> response_map_x = new Map<String, SFtoACSApex.AccountSelectResponse_element>();
            response_map_x.put('response_x', response_x);
            WebServiceCallout.invoke(
              this,
              request_x,
              response_map_x,
              new String[]{endpoint_x,
              'http://tempuri.org/AccountSelect',
              'http://tempuri.org/',
              'AccountSelect',
              'http://tempuri.org/',
              'AccountSelectResponse',
              'SFtoACSApex.AccountSelectResponse_element'}
            );
            response_x = response_map_x.get('response_x');
            return response_x.AccountSelectResult;
        }

    }
}
```

Then I created a controller class:

```
public class SFCallWebService
{
    SFtoACSApex.ArrayOfAccountInfo dc = new SFtoACSApex.ArrayOfAccountInfo();
    public List<SFtoACSApex.AccountInfo> getAccInfo() 
    {        
        SFtoACSApex.SFtoACSSoap sf = New SFtoACSApex.SFtoACSSoap();
        dc = sf.AccountSelect('10272');        
        List<SFtoACSApex.AccountInfo> al = new List<SFtoACSApex.AccountInfo>();        
        al.add(dc.AccountInfo[0]);      
        return al;
    }

     public String getAName() {        
          Account sAcct = [select Retailsite_ID__c from Account
                         where id = 
                         :System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('id')];   
        SFtoACSApex.SFtoACSSoap sf = New SFtoACSApex.SFtoACSSoap();
        SFtoACSApex.ArrayOfAccountInfo dc;
        dc = sf.AccountSelect(sAcct.Retailsite_ID__c);

        return dc.AccountInfo[0].AccountNumber + ' ' + dc.AccountInfo[0].AccountName;
    }
}
```

I can retrieve info from both on my VF page:

```
 <apex:page controller="SFCallWebService" tabStyle="Account">
    This is the info {!aname}
    This is the detailed info {!AccInfo}    
    </apex:page>
```

But when I do:

```
 <apex:page controller="SFCallWebService" tabStyle="Account">
    This is the info {!aname}
    This is the detailed info {!AccInfo.AccountName}    
    </apex:page>
```

I get error:

> Unknown Property 'VisualforceArrayList.AccountNumber'

I would like to display the info on a VF page - and ultimately have much more info displayed - in a table or something...I don't know what yet, but I figured I will decide that once I can access the properties.

I think I have looked at it too long and it is something obvious, but now I cannot see it.  This is my first time posting here and second day working with Salesforce so I apologize if this post is a mess!

Thank you for your help!

Edit:
Thanks Scott!  I thought of the AccountName as being a property of AccountInfo...Is this just a syntax thing? Like I said, I am new to this (bear with me) so I am trying to wrap my brain around how to access it.  Am I allowed to return a List of objects and then access the items of the object?  Much like using a datatable and getting the columns from it.  Is that not how it is done here?  If so, could you please provide an example...I have tried every possibility that I can think of...

This is the detailed info {!AccInfo[0].AccountName} does not throw an error in the Developer Console, but it does on the VF page...

Comment: The variable `AccInfo` on your VF is getting assigned as a `List<SFtoACSApex.AccountInfo>`, the property `AccountNumber` doesn't exist. You need to access the element within the array first.

Comment: ScottW, you can make an answer out of that. Doing so will allow others to upvote :-)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like WSDL2Apex does not generate the Setters and the Getters.
Try setting them manually. This is what solved it for me

public class SFtoACSApex {

```
public class ArrayOfAccountInfo {
    public SFtoACSApex.AccountInfo[] AccountInfo;
```

becomes:

```
public class SFtoACSApex {    

public class ArrayOfAccountInfo {
    public SFtoACSApex.AccountInfo[] AccountInfo{get;Set;}
```

and so on for each property.